# How to delete duplicate records in an unkeyed table in KDB

Tags: kdb

How to delete duplicate records in an unkeyed table in KDB? In other words, modify existing table and remove all duplicate rows from it

Answer (score 4):

From: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#distinct

> For a table, it returns the distinct rows:
>
> ```
> q)distinct flip `a`b`c!(1 2 1;2 3 2;"aba")
> a b c
> -----
> 1 2 a
> 2 3 b
> ```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to modify the original table and remove duplicates from it, not just query the unique data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is:

```
tab: 0!select by field1, field2, ..., fieldN from tab
```

where `field1`, ..., `fieldN` are fields which define a unique row. The `select` above will return a keyed table where `field1`, ..., `fieldN` are keys, then 0! will remove keys and return an unkeyed table.